# How can I retrieve data from different scope?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, scope, return-value

I'm working with an AWS query and I want the return value to be accessible outside of the function. As you can see I have a query function and inside is an if else statement. I want the value of 'success' to be accessible outside of this function.

```
docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
    console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
    null, 2));
    } else {
    console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    var success = data.Items[0].hash_key;
    return success;
    }
});
```

Comment: I removed the 'var' before success - and now it works outside of the function. Is this safe to do? Will it cause any issues with the rest of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable outside the function scope, then just change it in the function:

```
let success = '';

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
        null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        success = data.Items[0].hash_key;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried a few variations of this and I can't get it to work. I thought it might be taking some time to query, so I followed your code and added: setTimeout(function(){ console.log(success + ' did i work?'); }, 3000);     at the end and I still can't access it. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare something in global scope like markmoxx said.

But since this is an async call I imagine you're having issues with that variable being set in time.

I recommend a callback function.

```
let awsFunc = function( params, cb )
{
    docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
    null, 2));
            cb(false);
        } else {
            console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            var success = data.Items[0].hash_key;
            cb(success);
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can, somewhere else, call:

```
awsFunc( params, function(success)
{
    console.log("How'd it go? " + success);
}
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need to wrap your query into another function, you could use your anonymous function as the callback. The way I did it just makes it more clear elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I gave this a shot as well, but I'm not able to get the success variable outside of the second function, I want to be able to make it a global variable so I can use the hash_key for more in-depth queries - do you have any thought's on that?

Comment: Hey @Nathan, if you want the success variable outside of the second function, you just need to use the callback correctly. The second block of code I showed creates an anonymous function that takes a parameter. When we say cb(success), that's a way of passing the success result as a parameter to that anonymous function.

Comment: You also might start using ES6 syntax (if you can), since it deals with scope etc in a much more predictable way.